# Problema ao tentar receber a bandeira com checkout transparente em API do Pagseguro

Tags: angular, ionic, ruby-on-rails, pagamento-online

O problema é o seguinte, estou tentando implementar o sandbox do checkout transparente da API do PagSeguro, mas ao chegar ao passo em que a bandeira do cartão é obtido, ele sempre acusa erro e nunca segue apartir daí. O projeto está sendo feito em angular 9.1 e ionic 5.4.16. API em ruby on rails 5.2.4.4.
Mais um adendo, a documentação do Pagseguro adverte a obtenção do senderHash antes de finalizar o pedido, já tentei implementar dessa forma e agora estou tentando implementar no fechamento mesmo, mas o problema continua o mesmo.

Segue o código do app:

GET de id de sessão, implementado logo antes da tela de cartão:

```
  async createPaymentSessionId(): Promise<void> {
    this.loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: "Gerando token de pagamento...",
    });
    this.loading.present();
    this.http
      .get(`${environment.estacionamentoApi}/create_session_id.json`, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          EstacionamentoKeyAccess: environment.accessToken,
        }),
      })
      .subscribe(
        (res: { session_id: string }) => {
          this.paymentSessionId = res.session_id;
          this.order
            .subscribe(
              (currentOrder) =>
                (this.currentOrder = {
                  ...currentOrder,
                  paymentSessionId: this.paymentSessionId,
                })
            )
            .unsubscribe();
          this.orderSource.next(this.currentOrder);
          this.loading.dismiss();
        },
        () => {
          this.loading.dismiss();
        }
      );
```

Rota que é requerida pelo método acima no Ruby On Rails:

```
  def create_session_id
    response = HTTParty.post("https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/sessions?email=#{PAGSEGURO_CREDENTIALS_EMAIL}&token=#{PAGSEGURO_TOKEN_SANDBOX}")
    if (200..299).to_a.include?(response.code)
      debugger
      @session_id = response.parsed_response["session"]["id"]
      render json: {session_id: @session_id}, status: :ok
      return
    end
    render json: {errors: [{message: "Erro ao buscação Id de sessão Pagseguro"}]}, status: :unauthorized
  end
```

Método de finalização do pedido:

```
async finalizaPedido(order: Order): Promise<void> {
    PagSeguroDirectPayment.onSenderHashReady(async (response) => {
      if (response.status == "error") {
        console.log(response.message);
        return false;
      }
      this.finalOrder.senderHash = response.senderHash;
      this.paymentLoading();
      this.finalOrder.order = order;
      if (order.cartao) {
        const bin = parseInt(order.dados_cartao.cardNumber.substring(0, 6));
        PagSeguroDirectPayment.getBrand({
          cardBin: bin,
          success: (response) => {
            this.finalOrder.brand = response.brand.name;
            const params = {
              cardNumber: order.dados_cartao.cardNumber,
              brand: response.brand.name,
              cvv: order.dados_cartao.ccv,
              expirationMonth: order.dados_cartao.expirationMonth,
              expirationYear: order.dados_cartao.expirationYear,
              success: (response) => {
                this.finalOrder.cardToken = response.card.token;

                PagSeguroDirectPayment.getInstallments({
                  amount: order.plano.valor,
                  maxInstallmentNoInterest: 13,
                  brand: this.finalOrder.brand,
                  success: (response) => {
                    this.http
                      .post(
                        `${environment.estacionamentoApi}/pedidos/comprar.json`,
                        this.finalOrder,
                        {
                          headers: new HttpHeaders({
                            EstacionamentoKeyAccess: environment.accessToken,
                          }),
                        }
                      )
                      .subscribe((resp: PaymentResponse) => {
                        if (resp.errors) {
                          this.onPaymentErrors(response.errors);
                        } else {
                          this.onPaymentSuccess(resp.pago);
                        }
                        this.loading.dismiss();
                      });
                  },
                  error: (response) => {
                    this.loading.dismiss();
                    this.onPaymentErrors([
                      {
                        message:
                          "Erro ao tentar gerar opções de parcelamento, por favor tente novamente!",
                      },
                    ]);
                    // callback para chamadas que falharam.
                  },
                  complete: (response) => {
                    // Callback para todas chamadas.
                  },
                });
              },
              error: (response) => {
                this.loading.dismiss();
                this.onPaymentErrors([
                  {
                    message:
                      "Erro ao gerar token de cartão de crédito, por favor tente novamente!",
                  },
                ]);
                //tratamento do erro
              },
            };
            PagSeguroDirectPayment.createCardToken(params);
          },
          error: (response) => {
            // SEMPRE CAI AQUI QUANDO O TENTO OBTER A BANDEIRA DO CARTÃO
            this.onPaymentErrors([
              {
                message:
                  "Erro checar bandeira do cartão, por favor tente novamente!",
              },
            ]);
            this.loading.dismiss();
          },
        });
      } else {
        try {
          this.paymentLoading();
          const response = await this.http
            .post<PaymentResponse>(
              `${environment.estacionamentoApi}/pedidos/comprar.json`,
              this.finalOrder,
              {
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                  EstacionamentoKeyAccess: environment.accessToken,
                }),
              }
            )
            .toPromise();
          this.orderService.atualizaOrder({
            ...order,
            paymentSessionId: "",
          });
          this.loading.dismiss();
          this.onPaymentSuccess(response.pago);
        } catch (err) {
          this.loading.dismiss();
          this.onPaymentErrors(err.errors);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Está destacado no código para ficar mais claro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado desde já gente!!

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver, o problema era que o método PagSeguroDirectPayment.getBrand precisava ser implementando no callback do PagSeguroDirectPayment.getPaymentMethods

```
 PagSeguroDirectPayment.getPaymentMethods({
        success: async (dados) => {
          if (order.cartao) {
            const bin = parseInt(order.dados_cartao.cardNumber.substring(0, 6));
            PagSeguroDirectPayment.getBrand({
              cardBin: bin,
              success: (response) => {
```